# Was the Inquisition a threat to science?

Tags: history-of-science

Jeffrey Beall states [here](http://www.biochemia-medica.com/2017/2/273) (immediately under the heading "Predatory publishers and the threat to science" that he believes that "predatory publishers pose the biggest threat to science since the inquisition".

My question is not about predatory publishers, but what evidence there is that the Inquisition actually posed a significant threat to science, as Beall seems to indicate.

<sub><sub>Of course, if you wanted to be nit-picky about my notable claim, you could say that he simply states that there has not been a greater threat since the Inquisition, not that the threat that the Inquisition posed was great itself, but that is not how most people would read that sentence.</sub></sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60867/discussion-on-question-by-sgf-was-the-inquisition-a-threat-to-science).